# creating canvas lines with random/array generated co-ordinates. Not working, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

I can't figure out why the co-ordinates for the canvas lines aren't being digested using the arrays: any suggestions?

I'm trying to create an algorithm for randomly generated sets of lines which eventually link together from where the last one ended. like a snake that gets longer if you like.

```
     var c = document.getElementById("playground");
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 

  //global scope
  var i; 
var c1 = []; //c is short for collect
var c2 = [];
var c3 = [];
var c4 = [];

var initiate = function(){ //the buttom that triggers the program


var clock = function(){

 /* if(i){  
 alert(i); 
}*/

  i+=1; //increment each time the..
  //function gets called. 

 var a = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
 var b = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
 var c = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
 var d = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
 c1.push(a); 
 c2.push(b);
 c3.push(c);
 c4.push(d);


   ctx.beginPath(); 
   ctx.moveTo(c1[i], c2[i]);  //Here is where the issue seems to be? they don't run.
   ctx.lineTo(c3[i], c4[i]); 
   ctx.stroke(); 

    //if(c1.length===10){
    //alert(c1);
    //}

   }; //end of clock

    setInterval(clock,80);



    }; //end of parent function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `i` as `var i;`.  When you increment it, it results in `NaN`, so just initialize it as `var i = 0;` or the like instead.


EDIT:  Also why your problem is at that line is because you are trying to access the `NaN`th element of an array, which JavaScript doesn't like.

Comment: hmm, trying it but still no cigar. I still get NaN, hmm. I think i see the problem. I have i set to var i = 0; but i is incrementing ahead of the array before it's been created therefore still leaving me with NaN. i'll report back with results.

Comment: so i must be accessing a non-exsistant array index. so i'll add a -1 to the end. arrayCoOrd[i]-1; is working. Thanks ! saved lots of head scratching.

Comment: Here's the finished algorithm on codepen.io btw, just click the little button to initiate. http://codepen.io/Zulu/pen/GyuaA thanks again.